# Azure static web app - send email from the logged in user a week later. How to handle authentication?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I have an azure static web app set up with durable functions. I want the user to log in with their microsoft account, write a message and an email address, and that email will be sent a week later using the MS Graph Api.

I don't want to use `Mail.Send` application permissions as this lets the app send from anyone in the organisation. So I have `Mail.Send` delegated permissions.

After the user logs in, how can I send mail a week later, as the access token will have expired? Do I need to handle the refresh token manually or is there a built in way Azure Static Web Apps does this?

Answer (score 0):

No built in way. You will have to manually refresh the token in your backend until you need to send the email out.